# refreshing the action bar spinner after database changes

Tags: java, android, database, android-actionbar, android-spinner

I have an action bar spinner in one activity that gets populated using data from a database. I have a second activity that modifies the database (including data for the action bar spinner that is used in the first activity). How do I refresh the spinner once database changes ? I tried `notifyDataSetChanged();`, doesn't work. Also when I restart the app after doing the changes, they are reflected in the spinner so I can see modifying works, but only when I run the app again, not as the changes are being made

```
// this is inside the onCreate()

    // return a List<String> used to populate action bar spinner
    listUniqueCat = mDbHelper.getUniqueCategories();

    // create an array adapter to popluate dropdown list
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
            getBaseContext(),
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, listUniqueCat);

    // enable dropdown list naaavigation in action bar
    getActionBar().setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_LIST);

    // defining navigation listiner
    ActionBar.OnNavigationListener navigationListener = new OnNavigationListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(int itemPosition,
                long itemId) {

            selectedPos = getActionBar().getSelectedNavigationIndex();
            selectedSpinnerItem = listUniqueCat.get(selectedPos);
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
                    "you selected " + selectedSpinnerItem,
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


            return false;

        }
    };
    // setting dropdown items and item navigation listener for action bar
    getActionBar().setListNavigationCallbacks(adapter, navigationListener);
```

Answer (score 0):

Where re you calling notifyDataSetChanged()?

If you are doing database changes in second activity and when u go to first activty by pressing back button "on Resume" of the first activity will be called.

I think you should call

```
              listUniqueCat = mDbHelper.getUniqueCategories();   
              notifyDataSetChanged()
```

in onResume of your first activty

Comment: I go back to first activity using onActivityResult() because I start the second one using startActivityForResult

Comment: Then add above two lines in onActivityResult()

Comment: Is your activity is having one more adapter? If having one more adapter then please try yourspinneradapter.notifyDataSetChanged().

Comment: Have you tried yourspinneradapter.notifyDataSetChanged()? and if yes , please check your listUniqueCat is being get updated in onActivityResult()